# Svelte how to wrap an on:click event in a child and await the parents function?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to make a button component that will hide the button and display a spinner when it is clicked and is waiting for some asynchronous job to complete, and then hide the spinner and display the button after the asynchronous job is complete.

The key difficulity I'm facing is that I want parents to use `on:click` in this way:

```
<ActionButton 
    on:click={someAsycnFunction}
>
    Go
</ActionButton>
```

I do not want the parent to have to use a workaround such as:

```
onClick={someAsyncFunction}
```

Here is my `ActionButton.svelte` child component now. While this successfully wraps the call to the parents `someAsyncFunction`, I am unable to await the result of this.

```
<script>
  
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    let isRunning = false;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    // Wrapper function for the click event
    function handleClick(event) {
        console.log('child handleClick');
        
        isRunning = true;
        
        /* This doesn't work because the parent function is async
        * and there is no way to await on this */
        dispatch('click', event);

        isRunning = false;
    }

</script>

{#if !isRunning}

    <button
        on:click={handleClick}
    >
        <slot />
    </Button>
{:else}
    ...
{/if}
```

The `handleClick` successfully wraps the parent's call to `someAsyncFunction`, however, I do not see a way to await the `dispatch('click', event)` The result is that isRunning is set to false immediately instead of waiting for the parent `someAsyncFunction` to complete.

Is there any way to accomplish this while still allowing the parent to 1) not have to know about the internal `isRunning` and for the parent to be able to use `on:click` instead of something like `onClick` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function in the event object that signals that the operation has finished.
(If you want to also allow synchronous operations, you would need to also add some other function or property that signal what the `ActionButton` is supposed to expect.)

Here is a simple example that is async only:

```html
<!-- ActionButton -->
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    let executing = false;
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    async function onClick() {
        executing = true;
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            dispatch('click', { done: resolve })
        });
        executing = false;
    }
</script>

{#if !executing}
    <button type="button" on:click={onClick}>
        <slot />
    </button>
{:else}
    [Executing]
{/if}
```

```js
// event handler usage in parent:
async function onClick(e) {
    // [async stuff here]
    e.detail.done();
}
```

[REPL (has sync and async)](https://svelte.dev/repl/eee94d7ac9d54cfda80f11b03deb3007?version=4.2.12)

Note that passing callbacks will be the default in Svelte 5 rather than a workaround.

Comment: The only small issue is the need to call `e.detail.done();` in the parent component. Ideally, I wouldn't want the developers who are using the `ActionButton` to have to remember to call `e.detail.done()`.

Comment: Well, events are synchronous, so I doubt that this could be done significantly differently when using them. (Personally I would not do this anyway. Usually logic like that should go a form's `submit` event, not the button submitting it.)